# Vector to identity matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector `K=[3,4,5,...]` where the number of elements of `K` = `n`.

I also have a 3xn identity matrix.

I would like to place the numbers from `K` on the diagonal of the identity matrix i.e for `n=3`

`K=[3,4,5]`

V=

```
 3     0     0
 0     4     0
 0     0     5
```

I thought that `diag(V)=K.`' would work. But that presents an error.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
K=[3,4,5]
diag(K)
>>   3     0     0
     0     4     0
     0     0     5
```

Comment: You are very welcome. If your problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer, so others won't take time investigating your code. Thanks

Comment: Yup as soon as I can I will!